# How would I set up this enum to return the image I want?

Tags: java, android, enums, android-context

I'm trying to set up this enum so that it has the ability to return the correct image, though I'm struggling with a way to incorporate the context since it is in a separate class.

```
public enum CubeType
{
    GREEN { 
        public Drawable getImage()
        {
            return Context.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.cube_green );
        }
    };

    abstract public Drawable getImage();
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type Context

Comment: Context is a class, getResources() needs to be called on an instantiated object

Comment: I found a similar topic that helped me solve my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560511/static-access-to-an-android-apps-resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could have a context as a parameter to getImage():

```
...
GREEN { 
    public Drawable getImage(Context c)
    {
        return c.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.cube_green );
    }
};
...
```

}

Comment: I'm using the setup from one of the android tutorials. Like I have a class GameView which contains a class GameThread. Then I have a separate class (CubeObject) for the cubes and then finally the enum file. Is there a simpler way than passing the context from View to Thread to CubeObject to Enum?

Comment: Actually, I found a similar topic that helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560511/static-access-to-an-android-apps-resources

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define the enum in a class that wraps the enum and a HashMap relating the enum values to resource id's?

Comment: Not sure how to do this, though I get the idea of it.